# Prevent apps from opening in context of other apps

Tags: settings

I really dislike the "feature" where apps can open other apps "inside" their own context.  For example, I have a GitHub browser app that has registered the GitHub domain with my phone. When I click on a GitHub link from Chrome, the GitHub browser app opens by itself and is separately closeable (this is good). However when I click on a GitHub link from Yahoo Mail, the GitHub browser app is opened *within* Yahoo Mail, and it's not separately closeable (bad).

Is there a setting where I can direct my phone to only open apps directly, preventing the behavior I see in Yahoo Mail?

Comment: See if [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith) can help in choosing the app you wish to open with

Comment: @beeshyams, the defaults apps are fine. I just want them to open independently.

Comment: What I meant was that it gives you a choice of opening with and use that to open Yahoo links in GitHub browser

Comment: I am also annoyed with this "feature." Would like to find a way to fix it without root if possible

Comment: Coming to this question in 2023 because this 'feature' popped up for me today and I didn't manage to find a fix without root. Glad there was the option to remove the app and use the web browser to open the links instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Apps can launch other apps' activities inside their task. This makes
>   it impossible to switch back and forth between the two.

In that case you may use an Xposed module [ActivityForceNewTask](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.germainz.activityforcenewtask) (You need   [Xposed Framework](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053) installed as well as root)

This module sets the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when starting a new activity, which 'fixes' that.

It basically forces activities launched within applications to create a new task, allowing for much easier switching between the two. In this case if you click on a GitHub link from Yahoo Mail, the GitHub browser app is **not** opened within Yahoo Mail but as a **seperate task** with its own window, and it's separately closeable.

---

*Here is an illustration, showing how the module addresses the problem in  question*:

[image]
<sub>*Credits: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-activityforcenewtask-t2646504*</sub>

Comment: That looks like it does what I need it to do. I have no idea how to use it. It doesn't look like an app. Do I just throw it in a folder somewhere?

Comment: Xposed is a  Framework wich you can install then add modules to it, for setup please see this XDA support page :http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed

Comment: Not rooted right now... :/

Comment: I had a similar issue, where certain apps were opening inside another app and having one window but the ActivityForceNewtask solved this issue and the seperate windows makes it much more convenient for multitasking

Comment: Any way this is possible without a rooted phone ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using Firefox. You can disable opening links in applications and there is a menu item available called "Open in App".

[image: Firefox screenshot 1]

[image: Firefox screenshot 2]